# Segmentation fault core dumped 2d array

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to compile a c code under linux using gcc-4.9 (tried also 5.4) while so, I faced a segmentation fault error.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x080492e6 in dot (p1=0x8d9e6c0 <permy>, p2=0x3d77ca7c) at autrq.h:135
135     j = p2[i];
```

this is the part of code where the problem exists:

```
#define N 239
#define K 120

void dot(int p1[N], int p2[N]) {
    int p3[N], i, j; //printf("\n debut dot ");

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
        p3[i] = p1[i];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) { 
        j = p2[i];  
        if(j>=N){
           printf("Too large\n");
        }
        else{

           p1[i]=p3[j];
        }
    } //printf("\n fin dot ");
}

void GenAut(int permy[N]) {
    int i, j, c, f;
    //printf("\n debut GenAUT ");
    int inf[K], mo[N], mi[N];

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
        permy[i] = i;
    }

    j = GenIdex(1, 100);

    for (c = 0; c < j; c++) {
        f = GenIdex(0, pos);
        //printf("\n pos: %d et f %d ",pos,f);
        dot(permy, automorf[f]);
    }
}
```

`automorf` is an array n x n long (`int automorf[n][n]`)

Can you please help correcting the problem?

Comment: Likely `p2[i]` is not a valid index for `p3`. I would recommend you use a debugger to see what is going on.

Comment: Your code have just broken my eyes.Why can't you indent it properly? It is done automatically these days!

Comment: If you posted C code, why the C++ tag?  The variable length arrays, `inf[k], mo[n], mi[n]` are not legal in C++.

Comment: I changed the code with debugging results to make the error area clear

Comment: @Thomas Matthews It is not the truth, gcc allows them in the C++

Comment: Why didn't you add `if (j >= n) printf("j too large %d\n", j);`?

Comment: @Eugene Sh sorry about code form, I was in hurry

Comment: @PeterJ:  It is the truth.  GCC provides them as an *extension* to the language.

Comment: @mch Still the same problem

Comment: In `void dot(int p1[n], int p2[n]) {`, you don't have `n` shown in scope.  To be safe, you should have `void dot(int n, int p1[n], int p2[n]) {` or thereabouts.  Since we can't see what `n` is, there's no guarantee that the arrays are of any particular size.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews n is already defined as a constant it's not set at runtime

Comment: Just a note: I'd never pass that code in a code review. A `for` and its code block on the same line is horrible to read. If you want our help (which we're not even paid for) at least have the courtesy of formatting your code so we can read it.

Comment: @Almo sorry, I'm just using "gedit"

Comment: @Thomas Matthews. Yes but  _"I'm trying to compile a c code under linux using gcc-4.9"_

Comment: @pourjour I write better-formatted code in vi. Your text editor isn't a good excuse for making people work harder to help you.

Comment: @pourjour It does not matter. You need to declare the function properly. Otherwise it will be an UB and you ends in the segmentation fault. It is a good idea to check if the index has a valid value (add an additional if)

Comment: @pourjour `n` is *not* a constant.  It could be a macro name or a variable name, but even if it is the name of a variable with `const`-qualified type, it is not, itself, a constant.

Comment: @John Bollinger Indeed it's macro

Comment: By convention, constants are in upper-case; witness that everyone assumed `n` was a variable.  It is crucial that you show compilable code so that people aren't misled by your non-standard coding conventions.  We can cope if we can see; if we have to interpret, we'll get it wrong.  Read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).

Comment: To answer the question, we really need to see a [mcve] with which the problem can be demonstrated (at least in your environment).  My best guess at this point is that `GenIdex(0, pos)` is returning a value equal to or greater than 239 (`n`), but I have no way to test that.

Comment: no worries deleting - do not be stressed guys. Calm down. You dot like it I delete it,.

Comment: Error relate to dot() in which you try to writing in extra bound of array p3[j] possible j exceed the p3 array length.

Comment: @EsmaeelE I've added a verification for j>=n

Comment: @pourjour you must verify j is less than N after j = p2[i];  in second for in dot()

Comment: @pourjour make correct it : if (j > N ) print error and break;

Comment: @EsmaeelE from debugging I think that the problem is in accessing p2[i]

Comment: see what valgrind has to say

Comment: 'Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x080492e6 in dot (d=1170235, p1=0x8d9e6c0 <permy>, p2=0x4ab3b714)
    at autrq.h:135
135  j = p2[i];'

Comment: to ensure access to p2[i] is source of error comment all the second for .   insert p2[i]; in first for just after the p3[i] = p1[i];  to check only access to p2[i].

Comment: @EsmaeeIE I commented code after j =p2[i] and I still get the same error

Comment: @EsmaeeIE no more error now

Comment: are the segment fault error disappear.

Comment: @EsmaeeIE it works for p2[i] and not for j  = p2[i]

Comment: it's a weird behavior indeed

Comment: see what valgrind has to say

Comment: that's what valgrind says 
https://pastebin.com/eXaPwqnD

Comment: I'm trying to access p[d]; and d<N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and see output
 [image: output]

we have not `p3[3];` and trying to access make error or undefined behavior.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 3

void dot(int p1[N], int p2[N]) {
    int p3[N], i, j; //printf("\n debut dot ");

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
        p3[i] = p1[i];
    }

   for (i = 0; i < N; i++) { 
        printf("i:%d p3[i]%d\n", i,p3[i]) ;
   }

    printf("\n") ;


    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) { 

        j = p2[i]; 

        printf("i:%d j:%d p3[%d]:%d\n", i, j, j, p3[j]) ;

        p1[i]=p3[j];

    } 

    //printf("\n fin dot ");
}


int 
main(){

    int x[N]={10,20,30};
    int y[N]={1,2,3};

    dot(x, y);


    printf("\n");
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: @EsmaeeIE I get segmentation fault  in "j=p2[i]"

Comment: @pourjour if you exactly copy paste my dot() function

Comment: @EsmaeeIe tomorrow I will try to compile on another machine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148557/discussion-between-pourjour-and-esmaeele).

Comment: @pourjour if the y[] values not in range of x[] index we have undefined behavior. y[2]==3, and we have not x[3] then cause error.